# XML Digital Signature validation fail when using XSLT transform

Tags: java, xml, validation, xslt, digital-signature

I am trying to validate a digital signature of a XML file which contains a XSLT transformation. However when I validate this message I receive the following error:

> *javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: XSLT Transform does
>   not support specified parameter element: xsl:transform*

**The signature of the file contains a transform that looks like this:**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" method="xml"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../@codering = 'base64'">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(.), ' ', '')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**The code used to validate the xml file looks like this:**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = documentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document xmlDocument = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
NodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
DOMValidateContext domValidateContext = new DOMValidateContext(new RsaSha256KeySelector(), nodeList.item(0));
XMLSignatureFactory xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
XMLSignature signature = xmlSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(domValidateContext);
signatureIsValid = signature.validate(domValidateContext);
```

Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be using `xsl:` for the transform itself, i.e. before it is defined. Could you try and remove the first `xsl:` it or use the full name?

Answer (score 0):

Found self the solution for the problem. Apparently java XSLT transform only supports xsl:stylesheet and not xsl:transform. Althou W3C XSLT specifications defines it as synonyms.